# Add share button magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, social-buttons

I want to add share button in my template same as youtube share button for copy link. When clicking this button will show my current URL. [image]

click button

[image]

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: What will be the work of this share button? Does it share in facebook or something else?

Comment: @SukumarGorai I updated my question. It will be my current URL, the users can copy the URL by clicking "COPY"

Comment: Where do you want this? In product details page or somewhere else?

Comment: In my blog I created. I can get current URL and just don't know how to create that button.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below code for your requirement:

Add the below html code to desired location:

```
<div class="share-container">
    <a href="YOUR_URL" class="blog-share">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" focusable="false">
            <path d="M14 9V5l7 7-7 7v-4.1c-5 0-8.5 1.6-11 5.1 1-5 4-10 11-11z"></path>
        </svg>
        <span>Share</span>
    </a>

    <div class="dialog">
        <span class="close">X</span>
        <input type="text" id="copy"/>
        <button>Copy</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Add the below css code snippet to your respective css file:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .share-container{position: relative;}
    .share-container .blog-share{width: 50px; line-height: 20px; color: #777;}
    .share-container .blog-share svg{width: 20px; float: left; fill: #777;}
    .share-container .dialog{border:5px solid #666; padding:10px; background:#3A3A3A; position:absolute; display:none; z-index: 1;}
    .share-container .close{position: absolute;right: 0; top: -8px; color: #fff; cursor: pointer;}
</style>
```

Also add the below javascript code to your template or js file:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('.blog-share').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).next().find('input').val($(this).attr('href'));
            $(this).next().show(500);
        });

        $('.close').click(function(){
            $(this).parent().hide(500);
        });

        $('.dialog button').click(function(){
            $(this).prev().select();
            document.execCommand("copy");
        });
    });
</script>
```

You need to replace the url on href with your respective url.